# How to refer the current class inside it's static method?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have two classes

```
class AbstractPerson {
  static createFromPayload() {
    // here I need find the class that this method was called from
    // So, when I call 'Driver.createFromPayload()' I need to get a reference to Driver class here
    const ClassToUse = ...
    // get its static fields prop
    const fields = ClassToUse.fields;
    // and create a new instance of that class
    const result = new ClassToUse();
    // ... then do something with the fields
  }
}

class Driver extends Person {
    age = 0;
    firstName = '';
    lastName = '';

    static fields = ['age', 'firstName', 'lastName']
}
```

is it possible to get a reference to Driver class in createFromPayload static method of the AbstractPerson class?

```
get(...).then(data => Driver.createFromPayload(data))
```

Comment: Inside static methods, `this` refers to the class

Comment: You shouldn't. An abstract class should have no knowledge of its children. Have a look into "Abstract Factory Pattern". Many resources can be found, here is just one: https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/abstract-factory-design-pattern